# How to stop current URLSession if multiple sessions have been created?

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native, swift5, urlsession

Hi all pretty knew to swift,

I am creating a module in Swift connected to React Native. From react native I call a function which will return the status code (if found).

```
//React Native code
NativeModules.Testing.testURL("MyURL", (result) => { //do some stuff with result });
```

This all works perfectly, and I can call this function multiple times (passing in different URL's  each time). What I am trying to achieve now is to stop the current session.

I know I can use:

```
//Swift code
session.invalidateAndCancel()
```

But how would I know which current session needs to be stopped? For example in react native I have a list of 5 different websites. I click on each list item (website) which creates a new session (lets say it takes 10 seconds to fetch that website). If I want to stop session number 3 before a result is returned how would I go about that? Is there a way to keep track of current session from react native?

Basically in react native click the website > before result is returned > click again in react native to stop that session.

Any help is greatly appretiated. Thanks.

```
//swift Code
@objc(Testing)
class Testing: NSObject {
 @objc func testURL(_ tempUrl: NSString, callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) {

  func checkURL (url: String, completion: @escaping ((Int) -> Void)){
  
  guard let url = URL(string: url) else{
    return
  }
  
  let session = URLSession.init(delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.current)
  
  session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
    
    if err != nil {
      completion(404)
      return
    }
    
    if data == nil {
      completion(404)
      return
    }
    
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    if httpResponse?.statusCode != 200 {
      completion(httpResponse!.statusCode)
    } else {
      completion(httpResponse!.statusCode)
    } 
  }.resume()
};

    checkURL( url: tempUrl as! String, completion: { isSuccess in
      //Callback sends response back to react native after above session task has finished
      callback([isSuccess])
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think there's a misconception: you should not create your own URLSession every time you perform a request. Only create one and reuse it for several requests. Also you don't want to invalidate your URLSession, unless you are doing advanced stuff. Alternatively use `URLSession.shared` - which you cannot invalidate. A URLSessionTask (the network request) can be cancelled which is a pretty common requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add some specific logic to do it. Here is an idea that you can expand on if it works for you. How about change

```
@objc func testURL(_ tempUrl: NSString, callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock)
```

to include something that you can later use to cancel on, e.g.

```
@objc func testURL(_ tempUrl: NSString, index: Int, callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
```

then use that to check for cancel, e.g. inside `dataTask` change to

```
    if err != nil {
      completion(404)
      return
    }
    
    if data == nil {
      completion(404)
      return
    }

    // New stuff
    if mustCancel( index: index ) {
      completion(xxx)
      return
    }    

    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse

    // More new stuff
    if mustCancel( index: index ) {
      completion(xxx)
      return
    }    

    if httpResponse?.statusCode != 200 {
      completion(httpResponse!.statusCode)
    } else {
      completion(httpResponse!.statusCode)
    }
```

Here you need to come up with something appropriate for `xxx` (e.g. 409?). Then you also need to implement the `mustCancel` function where you need to decide if you want to cancel the URL associated with `index`. Heck, you can make `mustCancel` also take the URL as parameter if that can work.

**EDIT** Of course, if you need to cancel silently, then simply do not call `completion(xxx)` here.

Note that, since you are dealing with concurrent access you may need to sync access to variables in `mustCancel`, especially if the logic there uses variables outside of `mustCancel` that can be set elsewhere and on a different thread. I am not expanding on this too much but take care if you follow this with that step.